# preventing duplicate records when importing a delimited data file into salesforce

Tags: salesforce, duplicates

I need to load hundreds of contacts into a salesforce database from a delimited file that only contains first name, last name, street address1, street address2, city, state, and zip.  My understanding is that you can only use name or email address to see if a conact already exists in a salesforce database.

I want to be able to match on name, street address1, and city so that I can limit the duplicate records in my database.

Is this possible in salesforce?

Comment: anything is possible. what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are some options... I'll make it a community wiki post so anybody can chip in.

**Checks before / during loading**

There's a way to create a text field and mark it as unique or external id, then write a workflow rule that would populate it with `{!Contact.Name} + ' ' + {!Contact.MailingStreet} + ' ' + {!Contact.MailingCity}` when contact is inserted or any of these reference fields change. But then you'd have to somehow fill this in for all Contacts you already have (which is not totally impossible: export a report with all contacts, fill the field in, import it back with dupe checking set to contact's Id).

If it's one time action though, perhaps you'd be better not creating this field. Export data from SF report then make some matching in Excel etc and load back?

You could write a trigger for data deduplication but that's a bit nasty solution (by default whole load fails, it's more for flagging as error than somehow merging data). I don't think you want to go that way (can you use apex code or is your SF edition limited?)

**Checks after loading**

You could decide to load them all in and deal with duplicates later. Then run a report that groups contacts by these 3 fields and when a group contains more than 1 - you have a candidate to merge contacts (that's a button on Contact record).

You could also [resort to AppExchange tools](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=duplicates), there are tons of them!

**Other random gibberish ;)**

If they're people with whom you might do business but you're not sure yet, you might want to load them as Leads. Think of a Lead record like a business card you got on some trade expo. There might be an opportunity here or it might not work at all. So load them up, then you can click "Convert" button on the lead - this might create up to 3 records (Account, Contact, Opportunity) or merge into existing data which is also an option for you I think.